# Import composition api

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Supposed I have `index.ts`

```js
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'


const Todo = defineComponent({
  setup() {

    onMounted(() => {
      test()
    })

    function test(){

      return 'test'
    }
  },
  // You need to define an empty head to activate this functionality
  head: {},
})

export default Todo
```

And I have `Todo.vue`

```html
 <template>
    <p>
      Hello world!
    </p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Todo from './index'
export default Todo
</script>
```

Then importing it to other file using

```html
<template>
  <Todo/>
</template>


<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

import Todo from '../../components/pages/Todo/'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {Todo},
  setup(){}
})

</script>
```

I'm getting an error saying `render function or template not defined in component: Todo`

any idea where can I start to fix this?

Comment: Did you installed `@nuxtjs/composition-api`? https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup

Comment: yes i have it..

Comment: This is probably a syntax issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out :

```
<template>
  <h1 class="test">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./index.ts">

</script>
```

Comment: How can I export the component index.ts like `export default Todo` because im using it to other directory

Comment: you could do `const Todo=defineComponent({...}); export default Todo` inside `index.ts`

Comment: @kissu sure to avoid any issue with loaders

Comment: How can i pass the Todo.vue to other vue file, and use it like <Todo/> component

Comment: `import Todo from './components/Todo.vue'` then add it to `components` option `components:{Todo}`

Comment: I'm getting a `render function or template not defined in component: Todo`

Comment: But you didn't write it like `<script lang="ts" src="./index.ts">` and `import Todo from '../../components/pages/Todo.vue'`

Comment: because it says  Todo.vue is not a module

Comment: what about <script lang="ts" src="./index.ts">